# Input type range is easy to accidentally trigger when scrolling in mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-experience

I have range inputs which sit alongside 2 buttons. When you scroll on mobile safari it's very easy to accidentally move the input, however the buttons don't have this issue

This is the markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <button>-</button>
  <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10">
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

But this demo is probably a better way to see this happening:

https://wsor1.csb.app/

Why is this happening? It is just a browser qwerk? Are there any ways of mitigating it?

It's not that relevant but the React code responsible is: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-neumann-wsor1

```
const Row = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(10);

  return (
    <div className="cont">
      <div className="row">
        <button onClick={() => setValue(value - 10)}>-</button>
        <input
          onChange={e => setValue(+e.currentTarget.value)}
          className="range"
          type="range"
          value={value}
          min={0}
          max={100}
        />
        <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 10)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const items = new Array(50).fill(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return <Row key={index} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```